# Find values ​in the database starting from a session id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need display the value in the `ga845_clients` table ​​in the `atacado` column, that have `'s'` or `'n'` recorded, but they return blank.

Then when I call `<?php echo $this->session->userdata('usu_id');?>` in view, the ID is displayed.

I have checked that **usu_id** is the session ID and the same value from `id` of table `ga845_clientes`.

I created the following codes:

**Model** (Cliente_model.php):

```
public function getAtacadista($id) {

$this->db->select("atacadista");
$this->db->where('id', $this->session->userdata("usu_id"));
$query = $this->db->get('ga845_clientes');
return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller** (Cliente.php):

```
public function getAtacadista() {

$this->load->model('cliente_model');
$this->load->view("carrinho", $data);
$data['atacadista'] = $this->cliente_model->getAtacadista($id);
}
```

**View** (carrinho.php)

```
echo 'test1:'  .$data['atacadista'];
echo 'test2:'  .$atacadista;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! are you sure that the view is called correctly, it should be called after the `$data` being assigned, it's switched

Comment: also that code is selecting `atacadista` column, not `atacado`

Answer (score 0):

Remember, $data['atacadista'] dont exists on view, only $atacadista

Also move down the " load view " line, as everton suggested, they are swapped and $data need to be before.

And lastly, as a tip, session userdata can contain a bunch of info, and you should pass the name of the session, not of the value, maybe usu_id is a value inside an array, not the array itself.

Comment: I have made this, but still not working , and usu_id is a value from id, if i can do it, using only the collumn from db, in user line, userdata session not is necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your controller

```
public function getAtacadista() {
    $this->load->model('cliente_model');
    $data['atacadista'] = $this->cliente_model->getAtacadista($id);
    $this->load->view("carrinho", array("data"=>$data));
}
```

You should place the $data variable assign before the load view.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not sending your data to the view. change the sequence of your statements.

```
public function getAtacadista() {
 $this->load->model('cliente_model');
 $data['atacadista'] = $this->cliente_model->getAtacadista($id);
 $this->load->view("carrinho", $data);
}
```

Comment: I move down, but still not working, in my view its correct?

Comment: $data['atacadista'] will not available on your view, It will converted into $atacadista. Please use $atacadista in your view. Also, your model will not return a variable. It will return an array or an object. Print your return result on view using print_r($atacadista);